# How do you use Report Data Source in a Table?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a table with one column and I want it to use the Data Source of the Report. How do I achieve that? Here is what i tried.

```
<detail>
        <band height="450" splitType="Prevent">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="50" y="20" width="200" height="200" uuid="02138e52-a5eb-4582-8dc4-cbdfa329fd89"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="bd2fa891-6406-4354-99fd-98ad798da835">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.cloneDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="200" uuid="ae8c0727-017e-4a01-ad87-e0899c41ce54">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table 3_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="77f26a91-9eae-4ce7-abef-5a582db5611b"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[leitung]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table 3_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="e70f7a65-32f8-448d-80c6-62d63a3d8a96"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{leitung}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

Comment: `I want it to use the Data Source of the Report` what do you mean by this?

Comment: Also provide the code of `Dataset1` in your design.

Comment: Id like to use the parameter REPORT_DATA_SOURCE in my table which is the main datasource... at least i think it is

Comment: If you want to use the main datasource, then while creating `dataset1`, have you given the option `use same connection to fill the master report`? Also while creation of table, in `Connection` window, have you given the option `use same connection to fill the master report`?